# Можно ли как-то трансформировать код с языка С на язык С#?

Tags: c#

код находит все палиндромы, которые показывает часы в течение суток. Часы показывают время в 24-часовом формате.

Результат программы таков: `00:00 01:10 02:20 03:30 04:40 05:50 10:01 11:11 12:21 13:31 14:41 15:51 20:02 21:12 22:22 23:32`

```c
int main()
{
    int i;
    char h[3] = {'0', '0', 0};

    for(i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++)
    {
        if((i % 10) < 6)
        {
            snprintf(h, 3, "%02d", i);
            printf("%s:%c%c\n", h, h[1], h[0]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Или может кто-то подсказать как переписать эту часть?

```c
char h[3] = {'0', '0', 0};

snprintf(h, 3, "%02d", i);
printf("%s:%c%c\n", h, h[1], h[0]);
```

Comment: Если способ и есть, то очень сложный. Такой простой код проще руками переписать.

Comment: Не смотря на большую схожесть с# и c невозможно трансформировать ввиду так же значительных отличий. По-другому работа с строками, совсем не схоже форматирование. Вообще можно, но программы в открытом доступе которая сможет это сделать мне не извесна.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, можете подсказать как переписать эту часть?
`char h[3] = {'0', '0', 0};
snprintf(h, 3, "%02d", i);
printf("%s:%c%c\n", h, h[1], h[0]);
`

Comment: Не могу - не знаю С#.

Comment: Вы бы хоть сказали, что этот код делает. Сплошные секреты.

Comment: @aepot, извините, код находит все палиндромы, которые показывает часы в течение суток. Часы показывают время в 24-часовом формате.
Результат программы таков:
00:00
01:10
02:20
03:30
04:40
05:50
10:01
11:11
12:21
13:31
14:41
15:51
20:02
21:12
22:22
23:32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что языки схожие, мне проще было написать код с нуля, чем пытаться подражать исходнику.

> код находит все палиндромы, которые показывает часы в течение суток. Часы показывают время в 24-часовом формате.

Так?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10 < 6)
        {
            string h = i.ToString("00");
            Console.WriteLine($"{h}:{h[1]}{h[0]}");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод

```
00:00
01:10
02:20
03:30
04:40
05:50
10:01
11:11
12:21
13:31
14:41
15:51
20:02
21:12
22:22
23:32
```

На будущее, пишите в вопросе максимум деталей, чтобы не приходилось выпытывать из вас подробности.

В плане C#, то же решение например могло бы выглядеть вот так

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
        .Where(i => i % 10 < 6)
        .Select(i => i.ToString("00"))
        .Select(h => $"{h}:{h[1]}{h[0]}")
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(h => Console.WriteLine(h));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Да, все так. Спасибо большое, буду стараться лучше формулировать вопрос со всеми деталями.

Comment: LINQ во всей красе: шесть строк кода вместо четырёх (с простым циклом), памяти жрёт больше, работает медленнее. Тьфу...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а как по мне то решение линком лучше. Как минимум потому, что читабельнее. Потому что преобразования идут линейно. Не нужно думать вложениями(вложенными циклами). А по поводу работает медленнее - это же далеко не всегда играет роль. :) Лично я предпочел бы разбирать чужой линковый код из-за линейности преобразований) При чем чем сложнее преобразования - тем легче будет читать код именно линковый)